# Dynamic Where clause: not getting output

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I have made a dynamic `WHERE` clause in `SELECT` statement in `Stored Procedure` in `SQL SERVER 2008-R2.` It is created successfully but I am getting output as 0. Any Idea where I am wrong?

Here is my SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPData]
@Id int = NULL,
@Requester varchar(20) = NULL,
@Suggester varchar(20) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql=' [Id], [Suggester], [Requester] from CRM.dbo.Request_Table WHERE 1=1 '
If (@Id) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Id=(@Id) '
If (@Suggester) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Suggester like (@Suggester) '
If (@Requester) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Requester like (@Requester) '
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any Idea where I am wrong?

After you build your dynamic SQL you also have to execute it using [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

I believe this would be of interest for you. [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPData]
@Id int = NULL,
@Requester varchar(20) = NULL,
@Suggester varchar(20) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql='SELECT [Id], [Suggester], [Requester] from CRM.dbo.Request_Table WHERE 1=1 '
If (@Id) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Id=(@Id) '
If (@Suggester) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Suggester like (@Suggester) '
If (@Requester) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Requester like (@Requester) '

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
                   N'@id int, @Requester varchar(20), @Suggester varchar(20)', 
                   @Id, @Requester, @Suggester

END
```